# Quantum theories related to superposition of entire events

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition

If science, by accident or design, was to discover that the superposition of particles we already know of scales up to entire events (so different events are in superposition in the future, with some possibly never actually being experienced), which current quantum theories would fit that discovery? Note the idea doesn't have to assume Many Worlds, since there is no assumption all superpositions are realized elsewhere (and no assumption they are not, either).

Comment: There is only one quantum theory. I guess that by "which current quantum theories", you mean "which current interpretations of QM"?

Comment: Also, what is an event? As the famous Schrödinger's cat thought experiment shows, QM has no definite limits about what a superposed state may be.

Comment: And last, what do you mean by "discover"? Superpositions are not observables as such, pretty much by definition.

Comment: Your appropriate questions outline the difficulty of my asking the question about something so speculative without going on and on. But yes, I mean current interpretations of QM. I'm speaking of an event that generally matches our every day view of what is considered a meaningful, high surprise event, such as a car accident. The how it's discovered I cannot go into currently, but I can say that yes, any "discovery" of those type of superpositions would be by indirectly inferring their existence from other evidence. So my question is, among the current qm interpretations, are any compatible?